# Jasmine runs specs out of order with --random=false flag

Tags: node.js, express, unit-testing, jasmine, sharp

I am building an image resizing API that resizes the image and then caches it on the server. Before resizing the image, the code should search for a cached version. if a cached version is found, the app returns `res.sendFile(path to cached version)`.

when I run unit tests with Jasmine, I try to resize an image in one spec, then I search for the cached version in another spec. Jasmine runs the specs out of order, resulting in calling the function that searches for the cached version of the image before calling the endpoint that resizes the image.

I tried using `jasmine --random=false`, and the specs sometimes run out of order as shown in the image below. What should I do? [test script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lsnGo.png) [the right specs order](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vXtkE.png) [specs running out of order](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4zF9u.png)

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: You should have tests that aren't interdependent.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0):

I reached an answer in case any one faced the same issue. I should have added the `--random=false` flag in jasmine script instead of test script. [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TGV8H.png) instead of [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FJ121.png).

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)